# An issue with javascript syntax comprehension

Tags: javascript, keyboard

Could someone please explain to me this statement in Javascript :

```
var keyCode = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
```

Any help greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Keycode = window.event? window.event.keyCode : e.which


var Keycode;
if(window.event)
Keycode = window.event.keyCode;
else
Keycode  = e.which;
```

Comment: The result is the same, however in my development I'd rather use the ternary statement.

Comment: Thanks @Robuust, I'm using this statement in a javascript file, which I will invoke using a jsp page, but eclipse is giving me the hint :'Keycode cannot be resolved or is not a field" and I don't know why ? –

Answer (score 1):

This is the [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Here it is used to get the `window.event.keyCode` value if `window.event` exists, `e.which` in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers don't recognise `window.event`. This is called ternary operator. It's a way to be sure the code works in different browsers and a short way to write:

If window.event is not undefined then `keyCode = window.event.keyCode`, otherwise `keycode = e.which`

Answer (score 1):

It means

```
var keyCode;
if(window.event){
  keyCode = window.event.keyCode;
} else {
  keyCode = e.which;
}
```

You should see Javascript grammar.